# Testing react-select dropdown with testcafe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, react-select, testcafe

I'm trying to write a lib function to test all my react-select dropdowns using testcafe.
But it is not working as expected.

I try to find the react-select with the id '#my-dropdown' that is passed a prop to my component.
Also, I try to find the options in the dropdown and then select the option with the new value.

However, it doesn't seem to work as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Custom Select component:

```
<div className='Custom-select'>
  <Select {...props} classNamePrefix='customSelect' tabSelectsValue isSearchable={false}/>
</div>
```

Note: Props contain the id - '#my-dropdown'.

testCafe test case:

```
test('DropDown test', async t => {
  await dropdownValueSelector(t, { selector: '#my-dropdown', newValue: 'value 2' });
});
```

dropDownValueSelector

```
export default async (t, { selector, newValue }) => {
  await t.click(selector).click(selector.find('option').withText(newValue));
  const dropdownOption = Selector('.customSelect__input').find('input');
  await t.click(customSelect).find(dropdownOption.withText(newValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [testcafe-react-selectors](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-react-selectors) plug-in; it provides selector extensions that make it easier to test ReactJS components. These extensions allow you to select page elements in a way that is native to React.